# R: Looping over rows until condition is met, then start over in next row

Tags: r, loops

I have a table with orders per customer with timestamp. I want to know which orders happen in timeframe `x` after an order, and once the timeframe is over, start again with timeframe `x` with the next order. The new column should always say which one was the first order.

Best is to look at example below.

I tried some `for loops` with `next`already but could not make it work at all.

The data looks like this:

```r
x <- data.frame("Customer" =c(123,123,123,123,123,123,123,567), "Order_nr" = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1), "Order_datetime" = c('2018-11-24 00:00:25','2018-11-24 15:58:23','2018-11-24 19:10:29','2018-11-24 21:29:04','2018-11-24 22:03:59','2018-11-24 22:26:59','2018-11-24 22:36:13','2018-11-24 12:00:55'))
x
```

```
| Customer | Order_nr | Order_datetime|
| ------------- |:-------------:| -----:|
| 123      | 1 | 2018-11-24 00:00:25 |
| 123      | 2 | 2018-11-24 15:58:23 |
| 123      | 3 | 2018-11-24 19:10:29 |
| 123      | 4 | 2018-11-24 21:29:04 |
| 123      | 5 | 2018-11-24 22:03:59 |
| 123      | 6 | 2018-11-24 22:26:59 |
| 123      | 7 | 2018-11-24 22:36:1 |
| 567      | 1 | 2018-11-24 12:00:55 |
```

If I would want to know the orders within a 1h timeframe, I would like to have the outcome in column `1h bundle first order`, if it was 3h, it should be outcome of column `3h bundle  first order`

```
| Customer | Order_nr | Order_datetime| 3h bundle first order| 3h bundle first order|
| ------------- |:-------------:| -----:|-----:|
| 123      | 1A | 2018-11-24 00:00:25 |1A |1A|
| 123      | 2A | 2018-11-24 15:58:23 |2A |2A|
| 123      | 3A | 2018-11-24 19:10:29 |3A |3A|
| 123      | 4A | 2018-11-24 21:29:04 |4A |3A|
| 123      | 5A | 2018-11-24 22:03:59 |4A |3A|
| 123      | 6A | 2018-11-24 22:26:59 |4A |4A|
| 123      | 7A | 2018-11-24 22:36:1  |5A |4A|
| 567      | 1B | 2018-11-24 12:00:55 |1B |1B|
```

So I need to know that Order 4A, 5A and 6A happened within 1h starting from order 4A on, in the example of `1h bundle first order`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A collegue helped me find the solution:

```
Order_nr_3h = [] 
order1 = df['Order_nr ']
initial_order = order1[0] ##initials needed so the loop can start with a value
time = df['Order_datetime']
initial = time[0]
customer1 = df['customer']
initial_customer = customer1[0]
for i in range(-1,len(time)-1):
    delta = (time[i+1]-initial).seconds/3600 ## 1h
    if customer1[i+1] != initial_customer: 
        initial_order = order1[i+1]
        initial_customer = customer1[i+1] 
    if delta > 1: 
        initial = time[i+1]
        initial_order = order1[i+1]
        Order_nr_3h.append(initial_order)
    else:
        Order_nr_3h.append(initial_order)
        continue
df['Order_nr_3h'] = Order_nr_3h
```

I then had another loop around it for each time interval I needed (1h,3h, etc.)

Comment: you asked for R and you answered yourself in Python?

Answer (score 0):

```
so <- data.frame("Customer" =c(123,123,123,123,123,123,123,567), 
                 "Order_nr" = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1), 
                 "Order_datetime" = c('2018-11-24 00:00:25','2018-11-24 15:58:23',
                                      '2018-11-24 19:10:29','2018-11-24 21:29:04',
                                      '2018-11-24 22:03:59','2018-11-24 22:26:59',
                                      '2018-11-24 22:36:13','2018-11-24 12:00:55'))


learn <- function(date_time, df, hr.within, i){

  subject <- abs(difftime(date_time, df$Order_datetime, units="hours"))

  ifelse(i ==1, 
         thatrow <- which((subject <= hr.within) == TRUE), 
         thatrow <- intersect( which((subject <= hr.within) == TRUE), 
                               which((subject >= hr.within-1) == TRUE)))

  if(identical(thatrow, integer(0))) return()

  else{
    R2 <- df[thatrow, c("Customer", "Order_nr", "Order_datetime")]
    R2$x <- NA
    R2[,"x"] <- paste0(hr.within, "A")
    colnames(R2)[4] <- paste0(hr.within,"A bundle first order")
    return(R2)
  }
}


learn.wrapper <- function(date_time, df, hr.within=seq(1,100,1)){
  learn.out <- list()
  for(i in 1:length(hr.within)){
    learn.out[[i]] <- learn(date_time,so, hr.within[i], i)
  }
  return(rbindlist(learn.out, fill=TRUE))
}

learnery <- learn.wrapper('2018-11-24 19:00:00', df=so) #first argument is the time you want to ref. with
learnery
```

This assume all action happen within 100 hours, you may reset into proper duration window via `hr.within=seq(1,100,1)` and then recompile.
You may then row merge the result yourself upon reviewing its outputs.